# Is it a good idea to selectively upgrade software from newer releases?

Tags: upgrade, backport

I'm a Ubuntu 10.10 users, and would like to keep my OS up-to-date. However, for various reasons I don't want to upgrade to the newest Ubuntu release.

I'm thinking of manually upgrading select system components like the kernel, upstart, dpkg, gcc etc from 11.04, because I want their enhanced features. Will this break anything with my existing install? Can you guys share your thoughts?

Comment: There's always classic Ubuntu, in 11.04, that doesn't use Unity. You just set it when you log in, it'll remember it. I also noticed a sharp decrease in battery time in Natty, so if you run it on a laptop, that's something to consider.

Comment: @shintoist yes, I'm running Ubuntu on a laptop. Thank for the info. Does it eat more power even with classic desktop?

Comment: yes, supposedly it's the linux kernel itself suffering power usage regressions.

Comment: @shintoist :( sad news for any laptop Ubuntu user. hope all the issues in Natty will be resolved soon. thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixing packages from different releases is usually not possible (only in some special cases).

Usually there are a lot of bug fixes during the first few weeks after release so if stability is important for you just wait a few weeks before upgrading. As shintoist already wrote, you don't have to use Unity with Natty.

It's always a good idea to try it on a live system before you upgrade to ensure that your hardware supports the new system - for me a live system on an USB key worked without any problem, in contrast to the author of the article you linked.

Comment: @florian-diesch. you brought up the important point about "mixing packages". will give Natty a try this weekend before installing. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The person in the first article for some reason decided to upgrade from a live CD, you don't need to do anything quite so extreme. You just open update-manager and they're is a little button with the option to go up to 11.04, keeping all your setting etc.

As for unity, I like it personally but if you don't, not a problem, just change your session type to "Ubuntu Classic" once at log-in and you'll get a good ol' gnome desktop every time you log in :)

Simples

Comment: I take it like.. all my setting including existing gnome panel customizations and themes will be intact after Natty upgrade (in Classic mode, of course). if so, count me in, Natty! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried the upgrade to 11.04 twice.  it failed both times and i had to rebuild my system from a disc both times. all i got was a blank screen. i have since read that it is best to do a clean install from a disc as any and all existing bugs will corrupt your system. unfortunately, ubuntu no longer provides free discs.  i have since moved to zorin, where things actually work out of the box, i do not have to add required applications; flash, ubuntu extras etc.